# json mysql data to d3 plot

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js

I am trying to plot mysql data with d3. I am using php to convert to json format but it does not work yet! For testing purposes I followed the steps indicated [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) 
I used simple-graph.html with my own php file on XAMPP.

```
include('connect.php');
$result=$con->query("SELECT date, close FROM testable");    
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

It echoes in json format like so: `[{"date":"1-May-12","close":"43.32"},{"date":"30-Apr-12","close":"22.54"},{"date":"27-Apr-12","close":"21.54"},{"date":"25-Apr-12","close":"21.42"}]`

The graph gets displayed when I provide a json file but not with the php file.

This works:

```
d3.json("json.json", function(error, data) {        
data.forEach(function(d) {                              
d.date =parseDate(d.date);                          
d.close = +d.close;                                 
});
```

This does not work:

```
d3.json("tablecreate.php", function(error, data) {      
data.forEach(function(d) {                              
d.date =parseDate(d.date);                          
d.close = +d.close;                                 
});
```

All files are in the same folder.

Could someone please indicate my mistake?

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you get an error or does it not display what you expect it to display? Check the the output from your PHP script is the JSON (and only the JSON) you expect.

Comment: I get a blank page. sorry forgot that

Comment: As a test can you run your php script in the browser and then take the echoed results, save them in a file called xxx.json and then get the page to open that json? Just wanting to eliminate any possibility that the process of returning the data is corrupting it.

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it works indeed. So there should be no problem with the php. Could there be a permission problem on XAMPP though?

Comment: There shouldn't be a permission problem. If you can put the 'tablecreate.php' url in the url bar and it returns the echoed data on the screen, then it should be fine. Have you tried using the console to determine if there is an error in the script (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)?

Comment: I think you're narrowing in on the problem. have you tried to do the json_encode along the lines of the original tutorial (http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html)?

Comment: Update: I have used the code I posted at the top with echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); Now I get the plot in Chrome and IE. Firefox gives blank page though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the code you used to echo the json. It's not the same as the tutorial, so it might be a point of difference?

Comment: I managed to get the charts I wanted in Chrome. So there is no problem with data format or my php file. The problem is that Firefox 22.0 complains about this line:   d3.json("query_chart.php",function(error, data) It says ReferenceError:d3 is not defined  IE also indicates the same problem : 'd3 is undefined'. However, everything runs fine on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your full php source on how your sending the json output to your d3 script. One issue would be if your not sending the proper content type  header. Below is some content from the API reference of d3.

> Creates a request for the JSON file at the specified url with the mime
>   type "application/json". If a callback is specified, the request is
>   immediately issued with the GET method, and the callback will be
>   invoked asynchronously when the file is loaded or the request fails;
>   the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the
>   parsed JSON. The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs. If no
>   callback is specified, the returned request can be issued using
>   xhr.get or similar, and handled using xhr.on.

make sure you have issued the following statement before you echo the json output.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Thank you. It did not have any effect. Could it be a XAMPP problem? the plot gets displayed in the browser when i use json file but not on localhost.