# How to retrieve dynamic data in D3.Js from mysql for real time plot?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, d3.js

I am trying to plot the real-time data using D3.js. For the bar plot I followed [this link description here](https://gist.github.com/charlesdguthrie/11356441). This is the real plot I wanted but not through the "fakeData.json" file but for this, I wanted to retrieve the dynamic data from mysql. For this purpose, I followed [using-d3-with-a-mysql-database](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/01/02/using-d3-with-a-mysql-database/). Now, **To my problem**: it works fine for this

```
d3.json("data.json", function (err, data){....
```

**But when I replace** the data.json with

```
d3.json("index.php", function (err, data){....
```

I got **nothing in the output**. My problem looks similar [to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470571/json-mysql-data-to-d3-plot) but couldn't find out the required result. My php code(*index.php*) looks like this
`

```
//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from tbl1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

And, it's output works fine when copied and pasted into ***data.json*** file. My data.json file looks

```
[
{"name":"John", "value":21088},
{"name":"Kathford", "value":297},
{"name":"King", "value":2095},
{"name":"Tylor", "value":64},
{"name":"Edward", "value":35},
{"name":"Saddey", "value":23},
{"name":"Sandy", "value":29},
{"name":" Rita ", "value":28},
{"name":"Stanley", "value":25},
{"name":"Hiung", "value":21},
{"name":"Chang", "value":19},
{"name":"Bokki", "value":30},
{"name":"Amzod", "value":15},
{"name":"Allure", "value":2000},
{"name":"Jim", "value":4011}
    ]
```

And, Finally whole code for plot is

> final.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="everything">
        <h1>Real time plot</h1>
        <h2>Top Rating Standing</h2>    
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <h2>Data from<a href="#"> International Journal</a></h2>
    </div>


    <script>

//updatingBarChart.js

var setup = function(targetID){
    //Set size of svg element and chart
    var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        categoryIndent = 4*15 + 5,
        defaultBarWidth = 2000;

    //Set up scales
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0,defaultBarWidth])
      .range([0,width]);
    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1, 0);

    //Create SVG element
    d3.select(targetID).selectAll("svg").remove()
    var svg = d3.select(targetID).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //Package and export settings
    var settings = {
      margin:margin, width:width, height:height, categoryIndent:categoryIndent,
      svg:svg, x:x, y:y
    }
    return settings;
}

var redrawChart = function(targetID, newdata) {

    //Import settings
    var margin=settings.margin, width=settings.width, height=settings.height, categoryIndent=settings.categoryIndent, 
    svg=settings.svg, x=settings.x, y=settings.y;

    //Reset domains
    y.domain(newdata.sort(function(a,b){
      return b.value - a.value;
    })
      .map(function(d) { return d.Name; }));
    var barmax = d3.max(newdata, function(e) {
      return e.value;
    });
    x.domain([0,barmax]);

    /////////
    //ENTER//
    /////////

    //Bind new data to chart rows 

    //Create chart row and move to below the bottom of the chart
    var chartRow = svg.selectAll("g.chartRow")
      .data(newdata, function(d){ return d.Name});
    var newRow = chartRow
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "chartRow")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + margin.top + margin.bottom + ")");

    //Add rectangles
    newRow.insert("rect")
      .attr("class","bar")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value);}) 

    //Add value labels
    newRow.append("text")
      .attr("class","label")
      .attr("y", y.rangeBand()/2)
      .attr("x",0)
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .attr("dy",".35em")
      .attr("dx","0.5em")
      .text(function(d){return d.value;}); 

    //Add Headlines
    newRow.append("text")
      .attr("class","category")
      .attr("text-overflow","ellipsis")
      .attr("y", y.rangeBand()/2)
      .attr("x",categoryIndent)
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .attr("dy",".35em")
      .attr("dx","0.5em")
      .text(function(d){return d.Name});


    //////////
    //UPDATE//
    //////////

    //Update bar widths
    chartRow.select(".bar").transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value);})
      .attr("opacity",1);

    //Update data labels
    chartRow.select(".label").transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr("opacity",1)
      .tween("text", function(d) { 
        var i = d3.interpolate(+this.textContent.replace(/\,/g,''), +d.value);
        return function(t) {
          this.textContent = Math.round(i(t));
        };
      });

    //Fade in categories
    chartRow.select(".category").transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr("opacity",1);


    ////////
    //EXIT//
    ////////

    //Fade out and remove exit elements
    chartRow.exit().transition()
      .style("opacity","0")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .remove();


    ////////////////
    //REORDER ROWS//
    ////////////////

    var delay = function(d, i) { return 200 + i * 30; };

    chartRow.transition()
        .delay(delay)
        .duration(900)
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(0," + y(d.Name) + ")"; });
};



//Pulls data
//Since our data is fake, adds some random changes to simulate a data stream.
//Uses a callback because d3.json loading is asynchronous
var pullData = function(settings,callback){
    d3.json("index.php", function (err, data){
        if (err) return console.warn(err);

        var newData = data;
        data.forEach(function(d,i){
            var newValue = d.value 
            newData[i].value = newValue <= 0 ? 10 : newValue
        })

        newData = formatData(newData);

        callback(settings,newData);
    })
}

//Sort data in descending order and take the top 10 values
var formatData = function(data){
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
      })
      .slice(0, 5);
}

//I like to call it what it does
var redraw = function(settings){
    pullData(settings,redrawChart)
}

//setup (includes first draw)
var settings = setup('#chart');
redraw(settings)

//Repeat every 3 seconds
setInterval(function(){
    redraw(settings)
}, 3000);

    </script>
</body>
```

Its been couple of days I am mired with this. I will highly appreciate your suggestions.